# java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, json

I am fetching status from PHP in JSON format, but always getting:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value 43 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

My way of reading result from JSON

```
int strUserID;

......

strUserID = jsonObject.getInt("UserID");
```

And in php i am using:

```
$user_id = mysql_insert_id();
echo $user_id;

if(!$objQuery)
{
    $arr['StatusID'] = "0"; // unable to create user
}
else
{
    $arr['StatusID'] = "1"; // user created successfully
    $arr['UserID'] = $user_id;  // passing user id to android app
}
```

JSON sample on web:

```
 46{"StatusID":"1","UserID":46}
```

But on Android side not getting data into json format, because facing exception

may i know where i am doing mistake ?

Comment: can you add your `json` response?

Comment: Post your **Json data**.

Answer (score 2):

While returning the data from PHP you should encode it in JSON.
use below function

> echo json_encode($arr);

Answer (score 1):

In your php file remove

```
echo $user_id;
```

and use this after your else condition

```
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: you are right Ravi the `user_id` is appending in the response data.